# Is there a way to allow all external ip connections in FreeRadius?

Tags: linux, radius

I have a problem setting up FreeRadius server to allow connections from all external IP addresses. My hotspot system is based on CoovaAP and custom made captive portal which communicates with CoovaChilli (deployed on router, not on server). Router is connected to modem via ethernet. Captive portal communicates with radius mysql database to verify the hotspot authorization. Everything works until the modem IP address is changed.

Here is a sample from /etc/raddb/clients.conf:

```
client x.x.x.x {
  secret = 12345
  shortname = name
}
```

So, the x.x.x.x ip address somehow needs to be dynamic. And i dont know how to sync modem`s external ip address to radius database to make it work.

The question is: how to make freeradius accept connections from all ip addresses or sync modem`s external ip address into radius database.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, you can do a :

```
# All IPv4
client 0.0.0.0/0 {
  secret = 12345
  shortname = name
}
# All IPv6
client ::/0 {
  secret = 12345
  shortname = name
}
```

Comment: thank you.it works for me.
I will try the dynamic clients too.

Comment: Is this going to work for IPv6 or do I need to include second client "::/0"?

Comment: @PSSGCSim this works for IPv4, if you want IPv6 you need another entry.

Comment: Thank you @mat, could you please also edit your answer for others to find this answer easily?